# Pairing of characters in C

Tags: c

I am working on a code that reads a text file and then will count the number of instances a pair of letters occur. So for example the text file containing "aabbaa"

The number of occurences is aa =2, ab=1, ba=1

I was thinking I could use a 2D array like such:

```
char charPair[25][25] =   {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w ','x','y','z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
```

But that would only return one letter.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: there are better ways to do what you want. what is the reason you are using this method? also, how big is your input data?

Comment: You missed a pairing in your example didn't you? Should have had a `bb=1` as well. Anyway... can you show how your current code is looking for occurrences now? Are you looping through that array looking for pairs that match in your string?

Comment: You need a 26-by-26 array, and the values `'a'`, `'b'`, etc. should be used to compute the indices, not the values of the elements of the array.

Comment: Why not bash? `egrep -o '[A-Za-z]{2}' input.txt  | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: @eduffy: have you tried your code? It won't find `ab` or `ba` in `aabbaa`.

Comment: Don't know how to handle that with one stream .. this is getting crazy `paste <(egrep -o '[a-z]' input.txt) <(egrep -o '[a-z]' input.txt | sed 1d) | sort | uniq -c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important: if you declare a `char`-array, then entries will overflow if a combination occurs more than 255 times, so i will change that to `long`.

Also keep in mind your 2D-array should have indices for each letter in the alphabet you are using. I will assume it is 26 letters in this (for example only ascii lowercase):

```
long charPair[26][26];
memset(charPair, 0, 26*26*sizeof(long));
char* reader = yourInput;
char current = *reader-'a';
++reader;
char next = *reader-'a';
while(next!=0) { // assumes \0-terminated
    charPair[current][next] += 1;
    current = next;
    next = *reader-'a';
    ++reader;
}
```

The `-'a'`'s are so that the letter a will have row/column 0 and z will have 26.

**EDIT:** regarding your comment on how to best read the input: The code above assumes that the whole input is put into a string (\0 terminated)

```
FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb"); // (todo: add your error handling if 0 returned)
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
int len = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
char* yourInput = malloc(len+1); // (todo: add your error handling if 0 returned)
fread(yourInput, 1, len, f); // (todo: add your error handling if <len returned)
yourInput[len] = '\0';
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Don't you need to shift the value of `current`/`next` to be 0 based? Or are you implying that his `reader` is doing that? Otherwise `charPair[current][next] +=1;` is going to be some segfaultish addressing.

Comment: @TravisGriggs RIGHT, slight oversight on my part, fixing it, thx.

Comment: Thank you! How would you suggest getting the next? Currently the way I have been getting characters from the file is using. int character = fgetc(file) and then putChar(character) to display the character

Comment: @Uhsheesh added info on how to get `yourInput` from your input file.

Answer (score 0):

in c++'ish C, please convert as necessary, variable declarations, comments, etc...

...

```
char tCharPairCount[26][26]; // Lower-Case strings only
memset(tCharPairCount,0,26*26);

char tPrevChar = tempString[0];
for(int i=1; i<tempString.length(); ++i ) 
{
   char tCurrentChar = tempString[i];
   ++tCharPairCount[tPrevChar-'a'][tCurrentChar-'a'];
   tPrevChar = tCurrentChar;
}
```

...

// iterate results

```
for(i:0->25)
for(j:0->25)
 printf("%i",tCharPairCount[i][j]);  // 0,0 => aa ; 1,0 => ba
```